# XCode 4.5.2 started taking a long time to run apps on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I started noticing that it was taking several minutes (5-10) to build and run apps on my iPhone 4S from Xcode. I was running XCode 4.5.2 and iOS6.0 on my 4S and decided to figure out the problem. There was another similar question posted here but it was closed without a definitive answer. (which is a shame since this is a valid concern for folks.) I am reposting the question to explain what I observed. Hopefully it will help someone.

First I rebooted my Mac after several impatient attempts to install a relatively small app seemed to hang. I tried removing all of my old provisioning profiles from my Mac and my iPhone thinking I was having trouble with expired certs/profiles. I tried a few more times and decided to let it just hang to see what happens. It eventually launched the app on my device after about 5-10 minutes. I Googled around and found some hints that maybe I should try rebooting my iPhone and re-synching with iTunes. (I had already made an unsuccessful attempt at synching which also seemed to take forever.) On my next attempt to synch I decided to remove some larger apps (700+MB) to clear space since I was down to my last GB.

Things were still slow so I decided to reboot my iPhone and then re-synching it. I rebooted my phone and went to sync in iTunes again and this time the sync went quickly. I had cleared an extra 3+GB leaving me about 4+GB of free space. I restarted XCode and my app is now installing quickly.

My take-away is such that I believe there may be extra daemons running over time on the device and restarting my phone is what ultimately helped restore install times. Also, I'm not sure if clearing space helped or not. I would like to know what the root cause/solution is but that depends on others having similar experiences and responding.

Comment: this isn't really a question. programming any embedded system WILL have this kind of problem, and unless it recurs daily, if restarting the device solves it, that's honestly all you need to know as an developer of an iOS device. my friend's android completely stopped allowing his dev environment to transfer and run a build and no amount of restarting has solved it yet.

Comment: This is a question because if there are any steps, such as regularly cleaning between builds, clearing old provisioning profiles (I had about 20-30 of 'em on my device) can be taken to mitigate the problem they should be posted as an answer. Also I disagree that any kind of embedded programming will have the problem. I've been working mobile (Blackberry/iOS/Android) since 2007 and this is the 1st time I've seen it.

Comment: i literally meant you didn't ask a question. you just made statements, no question marks. Also, i'm severely shocked you've never had to restart a device to get a build to transfer properly in all your mobile development since 2007. I would venture to say you are the luckiest person in the world. I've been doing embedded dev since 1998 and can't count how many times i've had to restart hardware for no apparent reason, sometimes twice in one day.

Comment: Fair point. Now that I read I do see a glaring omission of question marks. Thought they were implied but I guess not. FWIW, I did have several occasions where I've had to restart my device where something was going awry but this is the 1st time I've noticed a 10 minute deploy cycle. I thought it was a bit odd and wanted to know more